# Estou fazendo meu site, básico, primeira vez. Porém, os icones sumiram

Tags: html, css, icons, font-awesome

```html
<div id="box">
  <h1>Home</h1>

  <img src="images/img-people.png" alt=>

  <input class="post" placeholder="What's happening?" type="text" /><br><br>

  <button> <i class="fa-solid fa-gallery-thumbnails"> galery </i></button>
  <button> <i class="fa-regular fa-gif">gif</i></button>
  <button> <i class="fa-solid fa-face-grin"> emoji </i></button>
  <button> <i class="fa-solid fa-location-dot"> tag location </i></button>

  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/21775648e6.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</div>

</body>
```

eu já tentei apagar o link e colocar de novo, já tentei mudar o cod do icone (mudando de icone), mas sempre o GALERY e o GIF nao aparecem seus icones.

[[image: screenshot da pagina]
<sup>clique para visualizar em seu tamanho original</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsH39.png)

Comment: Dê uma olhada em [gallery-thumbnails](https://fontawesome.com/icons/gallery-thumbnails?s=solid&f=sharp) esse é um **Pro Icon** ou seja só pode ser utilizado em kits Font Awesome pagos e o kit informado na pergunta é um kit gratuito. O mesmo acontece com [fa-gif](https://fontawesome.com/icons/gif?s=solid&f=classic).

Answer (score -2):

Se você olhar no site do fontawesome, os dois ícones que não aparecem são ícones Pro. No site deles você pode filtrar os ícones gratuitos.